# How to run javascript code without thread?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading

I'm Beginner in Javascript. I learned python before. In javascript, I noticed that javascript runs every function with thread. Example:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/',
        type:'GET',
        success:function(){
            console.log('Response Found!')
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('Error connecting to the site.')
        },
    })

console.log('All done!')
```

Here a jquery ajax request and a console log function. I want to execute ajax request before console log. But the result is:
[image: This]

Console log execute before ajax request. Can any one tell how to wait till the ajax function is completed?

Comment: While it's possible to run synchronous requests, it's **incredibly** bad practice and should be avoided at all costs. The better approach is to work with the async code pattern as intended. See the duplicate for how to do this.

Comment: The "A" in "AJAX" stands for asynchronous.  Not all functions in javascript run "in a new thread".  Javascript is single threaded - all of your code/library code/UI updates etc all run in a single thread.  The $.ajax call initiates a browser request then, when that's finished, runs the callback `success:` (etc)